# How to validate if a variable exist before inserting into table?

Tags: php, mysqli

How can I validate if $projectname exists and prevent it from inserting with a pop up window indicating error "This project already exists"?  I would also like to prevent any null inserts.

Please help!

```
$con=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "password","agent");

$idq="SELECT id_project, projectname FROM project, agentsInfo
WHERE (agentsInfo.idagency = project.id_agent) AND email = '$_SESSION[email]'" or   die(mysql_error());


$result= mysqli_query($con, $idq);

$row_number = 1;

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

$id_agent= $row["id_agentid_agent"];
$id_project= $row["id_project"];
$projectname= $row["projectname"];


$id_project++;

$row_number++;


}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

if ($projectname != $_POST['projectname']) {




$sql = "INSERT INTO project (id_project, projectname, id_agent)
VALUES ( ?,?, ( select idagency FROM agentsInfo WHERE email = ?))
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  //this is unnecessary, how do i replace this? 
`id_agent` = VALUES(`id_agent`),
`projectname` = VALUES(`projectname`)
";

if (($stmt = $con->prepare($sql)) === false) {
trigger_error($con->error, E_USER_ERROR);
}

$result= mysqli_query($con, $idq);

$row_number = 1;

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

$id_project= $row["id_project"];

$id_project++;

}

if ($stmt->bind_param("sss",
$id_project,
$_POST["projectname"],
$_SESSION["email"]) === false) {
trigger_error($stmt->error, E_USER_ERROR);

}


if (($stmt->execute()) === false) {
trigger_error($stmt->error, E_USER_ERROR);
}

} else {

//DUPLICATE FOUND

echo "<script type='text/jscript'>alert('This project already exists.')</script>";

}

}

?>
```

Comment: one way, since the project name is supposed to be unique, add a `unique` index for that column. Then whenever insert new record fails, check the error and find whether it failed because of unique constrain and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
$con=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "password","agent");
// New code
$query="Select count(*) as qty from project where projectname='".$projectname."'";
$result=mysqli_query($query);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
echo '<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">function doesexist() {';
if($row['qty']>0)
 {
 echo "alert('This project already exists!');";
 }
echo "return();\n}</SCRIPT";
// End of new code
$idq="SELECT id_project, projectname FROM project, agentsInfo
WHERE (agentsInfo.idagency = project.id_agent) AND email = '$_SESSION[email]'" or   die(mysql_error());
```

Just add a call to "doesexist()" to the the onload event of the body. If no project exists there is only a return, if it does then it alerts. I have not tested this code,so there may be a syntax issue, but the concept is sound.

Comment: Thanks but I could not implement this since other users may use the same project name.  I managed to add if ($projectname != $_POST['projectname']) { and it works but for only the last $_POST["projectname"] submited.  I need it to go through the whole table and search for a duplicate.

Comment: I'm guessing you mean you want to allow two different users to create a project with the same name. In that case, you just need to adjust the query to also check the user id as well. So the query would look like "Select count(*) as qty from project where projectname='".$projectname."' and userid=".$userid;", assuming userid is the database element that identifies the user and $userid is a php variable that has the user's id.